# Jacobian of the observation model?

Tags: kalman-filter

The state vector is 
$$ \textbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ v_{x} \\ v_{y} \end{bmatrix}$$

transition function is 
$$
\textbf{X}_{k} = f(\textbf{X}_{k-1}, \Delta t) =
\begin{cases} 
x_{k-1} + v_{xk} \Delta t \\
y_{k-1} + v_{yk} \Delta t 
 \end{cases} 
$$

$z_{b} = atan2(y, x)$ and
$z_{r} = \sqrt{ x^{2} + y^{2}}$

the Jacobian of the observation model:
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} =
 \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-y}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & \frac{1}{x(1+(\frac{y}{x})^{2})} & 0 & 0 \\
                 \frac{x}{\sqrt{ x^{2} + y^{2}}} & \frac{y}{\sqrt{ x^{2} + y^{2}}} & 0 & 0 
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

My question is how  the Jacobian of the observation model has been obtained? and why it is 2X4?

the model from [Kalman filter](http://www.mrpt.org/Kalman_Filters).

Comment: Rather than appending the answer to the question, add your answer as an answer -- this is both allowed and encouraged, since it will indicate that the question has an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Jacobian is of size $2\times 4$ because you have four state elements and two measurement equations.

The [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of the measurement model is the matrix where each $i,j$ element corresponds to the partial derivative of the $i$th measurement equation with respect to the $j$th state element.

Comment: thanks for being informative and helpful. This is what I thought.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the problem by applying
$$  \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial z_{b}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial z_{b}}{\partial y} &
\frac{\partial z_{b}}{\partial v_{x}} & \frac{\partial z_{b}}{\partial v_{y}} \\
\frac{\partial z_{r}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial z_{r}}{\partial y} &
\frac{\partial z_{r}}{\partial v_{x}} & \frac{\partial z_{r}}{\partial v_{y}}
\end{bmatrix}  =
 \begin{bmatrix}  \frac{-y}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & \frac{1}{x(1+(\frac{y}{x})^{2})} & 0 & 0 \\
      \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}} & \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}} & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: This is not a correct answer to the question, or the question was not worded correctly. Either way it is misleading for future readers.

Comment: @CroCo - Please update either your question or answer. As far as I can see, your question isn't very clear and this answer doesn't answer what you appear to have asked.

Comment: @MarkBooth, thanks for the advice. Please remove the put on hold.

Comment: Sorry @CroCo, but I still don't see how your answer is related to the actual question that you asked, which was *My question is how the Jacobian of the observation model has been obtained? and why it is 2X4?*

Comment: I don't see any problem with my answer except that the element (1,2) seems wrong in the given model. It should be $$\frac{x}{y^{2+x^{2}}}$$. That's all I can say. If you think this is a wrong answer, would you kindly suggest the correct one instead of putting it on hold. It is easy to criticize a guy, but it is not easy to guide him/her. It is up to you, I don't really care any more. Any way, thanks again.

Comment: This is my code to solve the problem in Matlab                     'text' >> syms input output x y vx vy zb zr
>> zb = atan(y/ x);
>> zr = sqrt(x^2+y^2);
>> output = [zr; zb];
>> input = [x; y; vx; vy];
>> jacobian(output, input) text

Comment: How did you even derivate atan2??

Comment: @Mehdi, you can do using Matlab.

Comment: wouldn't it cause some inconsistencies if you use the derivative of atan while you use atan2 in the function?